# How to categorize the data and plot a graph

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2, bar-chart

https://www.kaggle.com/nowke9/ipldata ---- contains the data set.

This is an Exploratory data analysis performed on two IPL data sets. I am looking to establish relationship between toss won by the team and winner of the match from the matches data set. When I split the data into winner and loser using the ifelse condition and plot the graph, I am getting the output as a single bar graph containing only the total number of matches and all of it is part of the lost legend.

Here is the code -

```
library(tidyverse)

deliveries_tbl <- read.csv("data/deliveries_updated.csv")
matches_tbl <- read.csv("data/matches_updated.csv")

matches_normal_result_tbl <- matches_tbl[matches_tbl$result == "normal",]

# Is winning toss really an adnavtage ? ----
matches_normal_result_tbl$toss_match <- ifelse(as.character(matches_normal_result_tbl$toss_winner)== 
                                                    as.character(matches_normal_result_tbl$winner), 
                                                    "Won", "Lost")

ggplot(matches_normal_result_tbl[which(!is.na(matches_normal_result_tbl$toss_match)),], aes(toss_match, fill = toss_match))+
    geom_bar()+
    xlab("Toss")+ ylab("Number of matches won")+
    ggtitle("How much of advantage is winning the toss ?")
```

The output is as follows :-

[image: Is winning the toss an advantage ?]

How to split the data into two columns of winner and loser and get two bar graphs ?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you provide a small part of the data here (using `dput`), which will facilitate an answer. You shouldn't expect others tp download 18 Mb of data.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Marc. Actually I am fairly new to R Programming and I am not quite sure of how to generate data using  the dput() function. However I am sharing the data.frame of the first fifteen rows of the data set. Hope this helps out.

Comment: toss_winner_data <- data.frame(toss_winner = c("RCB", "RPS", "KKR", "KXIP", "RCB", "SRH", "MI", "RCB", "RPS", "MI", "KKR", "MI", "GL", "SRH", "DD"), match_winner = c("SRH", "RPS", "KKR","KXIP","RCB","SRH","MI","KXIP","DD","MI","KKR","MI","GL","KKR","DD"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate number of matches won based on toss, you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

matches %>%
  mutate(toss_match = ifelse(toss_winner == winner, "Won", "Loss")) %>%
  count(toss_match) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(toss_match, n, fill = toss_match) + 
  geom_col() + 
  xlab("Toss")+ ylab("Number of matches won")+
  ggtitle("How much of advantage is winning the toss ?")
```

[image]

You can go further and do the same analysis for top cities where the matches were played.

```
matches %>%
  mutate(toss_match = ifelse(toss_winner == winner, "Won", "Loss")) %>%
  count(city, toss_match) %>%
  group_by(city) %>%
  filter(all(n > 10)) %>%
  mutate(n = n/sum(n) * 100) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(city, n, fill = toss_match) + 
  geom_col() + 
  xlab("City")+ ylab("Percentage") + 
  ggtitle("Advantage of winning toss in each city")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer. However, the output is still showing an error :-                                    **Error in Ops.factor(toss_winner, winner) : 
  level sets of factors are different**  .                                                                                                                  When I put double quotations on **toss_winner** and **winner** in the **mutate** statement, I am getting an output like how I got in the question.

Comment: @SriSreshtan Don't put double quotes around column name. Do `matches <- type.convert(matches, as.is = TRUE)` and try the above code again.

Comment: Got it . Thanks . What is the implication of the above code that you have sent ?

Comment: It converts numbers/characters which are stored as factors to their respective type. Check `?type.convert`